# how to find formula that matches pattern

Tags: pattern-recognition

I have a pattern that I'm struggling to find the formula for.

For inputs of 0 - 3, the expected result is 0.
For inputs 4 - 6, the expected result is 3.
7 - 9 should output 6.
10 - 12 should output 9.
13 - 15 should output 12.
16 - 18 should output 15.
... this pattern repeats ...

```
 0, 1, 2, 3 = 0
    4, 5, 6 = 3
    7, 8, 9 = 6
   10,11,12 = 9
   13,14,15 = 12
   16,17,18 = 15
   ...
```

I'm not as interested in the 0 - 3 part that doesn't "fit the pattern", I can code around that.  It's the part of the pattern that repeats that I'm most interested in.  How do I "convert" a pattern like this to a "formula"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\div$ be the integer division operator, then
$$a(n)=3\left(\left(n-1\right) \div 3\right)$$
fits the pattern.

Comment: I don't think so- for example, the expected output for an input of 9 is 6. `3(9 ÷ 3) = 9` right?

Comment: Oh. I certainly overlooked that. Edited the answer.